# Clicking with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, click

I looked around, but I wasn't able to find anything that answered the question that I have at hand. I want to click a button with Selenium, but the button ID is dynamic (meaning it changes after EACH button press). I would like to click the button via it's value, but with Selenium IDE, the Firefox extension, I'm not positive how I could go about this. Here's the coding of the button that I'm trying to click, with Selenium.

```
<input id="move247957048" type="button" style="width: 120px" value="Sacred Sword">
```

The input id="move" that you see, it changes every single time I click this button. All of it changes except for the first digit, the 2. With Selenium, I have no clue whatsoever about how I could click this button via it's value, or whatever would work. D: It's repetitive as well, so it'd handle it multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Selenium IDE you can use xpath defined locators, in your case I would use next xpath `//input[@value='Sacred Sword']`. You can find it in related documentation http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#test-case-pane
[image]

Comment: How do I use xpath in Selenium? My format is set to HTML, so.. unsure. :c

Comment: Well..when I go to execute it, this is what the result is: http://prntscr.com/3ih5yb

However, if I right click on //input[@value='Sacred Sword'] and execute it that way, it works. It won't work any other way..